# if I enter name = any one of the names I got only the results of name = "Rashad and I don't know how to fix this bug (BTW it is just a fun program

Tags: function, if-statement, conditional-statements

When I enter any value for name, the function usually only returns the value of name = Rashad
and I don't know where the bug is
I'm sorry for asking such a naive question but this is my first program I'm just writing it for fun
`

[image]

Comment: Please add your codes as plain text

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Goodluck 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.